# Mouse pointer plug in

Tags: css, internet-explorer, plugins

I am developing a website where i am using CSS based layouts with absoulate positions. I would like to know is there any plug in for IE 8 which will tell based on the mouse where i am moving with the position (In Pixels).

I want to know with out any JS. I am looking is there any external plug in which will allow me to find out the position.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, so you will probably not get a good answer.  Please try again and tell us exactly what you want to know, why you want to know it, and how you want it to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a plug-in for the browser that will show you the mouse cursor’s position, whilst you’re developing the site?

I haven’t heard of any plug-ins, but you might try [Andy Budd’s layout grid bookmarklet](http://www.andybudd.com/archives/2006/07/layout_grid_bookmarklet/).

Doesn’t quite give you the mouse cursor’s position, but might make it possible to make it out.